# RESTFul Single Sign on Java API for session less web application

Tags: java, session, single-sign-on, socialauth

I am using JBOSS RESTEasy api for my web application. I am right now using java [socialauth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) api for single sing on service. My web application has no session implementation, everything as singleton. I am facing problem for maintaining session of social auth object for multiple user. Is there any other java SSO API which is not session based and i can implement in my web application.